# Motorized inversion chair (or table) that flip person on stomach?

Tags: exercise, stomach, physical-therapy

Are there motorized inversion chairs/tables that will allow a person to remain strapped in, and flip on their stomach?  I'd like it to be motorized as well.  All of the inversion chairs/tables I'm seeing flip you upside down or on your back, but do not tilt you forward.  I'm specifically looking for a chair, actually.  But if there are only tables, I'd like to see them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a product recommendation for a non fitness product.

Comment: It's not a product recommendation.  I'm simply trying to figure out the best and safest way to flip a person with Spinal Muscular Atrophy on their stomach, because they have contractures, and cannot physically do it.

Comment: https://www.myhealthybeginning.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/How-to-do-an-inversion.pdf

Comment: It still isn't about fitness or using the equipment in a fitness program.

Comment: Actually it is for a fitness program for the patient.  We're trying to provide a fitness program for this patient, because they don't have the ability to change their body orientation to their stomach.

Comment: If you can add that as context, the question can be reopened.

Comment: However, you would need to word it fairly specifically so it doesn't sound like a medical intervention.